# AES - running time in Python

Tags: aes

How long will it take for AES to encrypt a 128-bit message in Python on average?

I create a certain algorithm and test it here:

https://repl.it/languages/python

I want to compare the algorithm's running times with AES 1:1 (the same language, the same intepreter and so on). And this is very difficult, because either I meet some incomprehensible implementations and tests of time or time are measured with hardware acceleration. I know that Python is slow, but now I'm working in Python - and I program very poorly, so I don't have many other options.

So the question is simple - how much time will it take to encrypt in Python on an average computer? I even found the code in Python, but I can't run it:

https://github.com/boppreh/aes

Comment: what stops you from running and timing the code ?

Comment: I got: "Usage: ./aes.py encrypt "key" "message"
Running tests...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 540, in <module>
    run()
NameError: name 'run' is not defined". I don't know what is wrong. I also don't understand what this program does. It performs 30000 encryptions, probably?

Comment: By the way I have antoher code:

https://gist.github.com/jeetsukumaran/1291836

It looks simpler and it works. But now I'm not sure - is it all AES or they made some simpler version. Boxes looks like they are smaller. Encryption and decrytpion takes about 0,001 sec. I'm using this exactly: https://pastebin.com/m4YiPuKj